# Converting std::string to boost::posix_time::ptime

Tags: c++, boost

The following code converts a `std::string` to a `boost::posix_time::ptime`.

After profiling I saw that most of the time spent in that function (about 90%) is wasted with the allocation of the memory for the `time_input_facet`. I have to admit that I don't fully understand the following code, and specially why the `time_input_facet` has to be allocated on the free memory.

```
using boost::posix_time;

const ptime StringToPtime(const string &zeitstempel, const string &formatstring)
{
    stringstream ss;
    time_input_facet* input_facet = new time_input_facet();
    ss.imbue(locale(ss.getloc(), input_facet));
    input_facet->format(formatstring.c_str());

    ss.str(zeitstempel);
    ptime timestamp;

    ss >> timestamp;
    return timestamp;
}
```

**Do you see any way to get rid of the allocation?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the input_facet static inside the function:

```
static time_input_facet *input_facet = new time_input_facet();
```

This will construct the facet only on the first function call and will reuse the facet. I believe that the facet allows multiple consequent calls on the same object.

Updated: you also don't need to construct both the stringstream and locale. Just do it once either in a separate function or here in the static initialization, and use the stream consequently.

Updated2:

```
const ptime StringToPtime(const string &zeitstempel, const string &formatstring)
{
  static stringstream ss;
  static time_input_facet *input_facet = NULL;
  if (!input_facet)
  {
    input_facet = new time_input_facet(1);
    ss.imbue(locale(locale(), input_facet));
  }

  input_facet->format(formatstring.c_str());

  ss.str(zeitstempel);
  ptime timestamp;

  ss >> timestamp;
  ss.clear();
  return timestamp;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand who calls `delete` for the `time_input_facet`? And can I use the same `time_input_facet` for many different convertions with different format strings?

Comment: [std::locale](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/~locale) calls delete for you.

Comment: Yes, the input_facet is never destructed (only on the program exit). This is a small price to pay if it improves the performance by 90% by removing the redundant allocations. Of course, you can make it static global or a class member, so it will be destructed properly.

Comment: To prevent `delete` from being called, you have to pass a non-zero number to the constructor ([see here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/facet/facet)). For example, `time_input_facet input_facet(1);`

Comment: @VladimirSinenko: If I make the input_facet as static variable in my function, according to Jesse the temporary created `locale` object will call delete after the first function call. So I will have a dangling pointer and it won't work? If I combine your answer and Jesses comment, I should use a static variable in combination with a non-zero number in the constructor of the time_input_fact. Do you agree?

Comment: @VladimirSinenko: Perhaps you could edit your answer to call the facet constructor with parameter `1` (as indicated by Jesse) for reference. Then I accept your answer.

Comment: I ended up with this solution: `static boost::scoped_ptr<time_input_facet> input_facet(1);`

Comment: Here you go. Everything is constructed once and reused.